# Client side multiplexing using thrift in nodejs

Tags: node.js, thrift

How to implement client side multiplexing using thrift in nodejs?

I tried the below code, but in vain.

```
var transport = thrift.TBufferedTransport;
var protocol = thrift.TBinaryProtocol;
var multiplexer = thrift.Multiplexer;

var ip = 'localhost';
var port = 9090;
var connection = thrift.createConnection(ip, port, {
  transport : transport,
  protocol : protocol
});
multiplexer();
var client = multiplexer.prototype.createClient(
  "myServiceName", myServiceClient, connection
);
```

When I use the above client and call a method/function that is defined in my service,
 connection is being made smoothly (no connection error) and
 service method/function runs smoothly and returns the output.
But upon receiving the data (buffered) connection.js in thrift npm module throws "Cannot set property '0' of undefined" error.
On further investigation I found that seqid which is set on each client creation, is not being set.

Can someone please help me on this?

Answer (score 2):

I found this to be the solution for the client:

```js
var transport = thrift.TBufferedTransport;
var protocol = thrift.TBinaryProtocol;
var multiplexer = thrift.Multiplexer;

var ip = 'localhost';
var port = 9090;
var connection = thrift.createConnection(ip, port, {
  transport : transport,
  protocol : protocol
});

var multiplexer = new thrift.Multiplexer();
var client = multiplexer.createClient(
  "myServiceName", myServiceClient, connection
);
```